# Oracle PLSQL: different behavior with two different DBs

Tags: oracle, plsql

I wrote myself a little PL/SQL utility. Executing it (using SQL-Developer) against one DB (an Oracle XE installation on my Windows 10 Laptop) it works perfectly fine, but executing it against an other DB (also Oracle XE but on a Linux server) I am getting compile errors in my script!?!? How can that be?

The errors I get are:

```
ORA-06550: line 17, column 35:
PLS-00491: numeric literal required
ORA-06550: line 18, column 35:
PLS-00491: numeric literal required
ORA-06550: line 19, column 35:
PLS-00491: numeric literal required
ORA-06550: line 20, column 35:
PLS-00491: numeric literal required
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
```

The referenced locations are in this section at the begin of my script:

```
DECLARE
    -- limits and boundaries    
    MAX_NAME_LENGTH         CONSTANT NUMBER(3)          := 30; -- for table and column names
    MAX_VALUE_LENGTH        CONSTANT NUMBER(5)          := 10000; -- for column values

    -- our starting point:
    m_owner                 VARCHAR2(MAX_VALUE_LENGTH)  := 'C##TEST';
    m_start_table_name      VARCHAR2(MAX_NAME_LENGTH)   := 'XML_MELDUNG_QUEUE'; 
    m_start_column_name     VARCHAR2(MAX_NAME_LENGTH)   := 'XML_MELDUNG_ID'; 
    m_start_value           VARCHAR2(MAX_VALUE_LENGTH)  := '5647'; 
...
```

and the exact spot turned out to be the usages of the constants, i.e. the "...(MAX_....)"-clauses.

It seems as if on the second system the CONSTANT-definitions and the usage of these constants in further declarations does not work the same way as it does when targeting my local DB.

I am completely puzzled! What is the problem here? Why would such a PL/SQL declaration work using one Oracle XE DB but not when using another? I mean: I would understand, if some entity can not be found, but compile errors (or not) depending on the DB used???

Any idea or pointer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declaring variable lengths using constants is a feature added in Oracle Database 12.2.

So I suspect that your local installation of XE is 18c. And the other is 11.2.

You can verify this by running:

```
select * from v$version;
```